# How to convert a list of tensors into a torch::Tensor?

Tags: c++, torch, libtorch

I'm trying to convert the following Python code into its equivalent libtorch:

```py
tfm = np.float32([[A[0, 0], A[1, 0], A[2, 0]],
                  [A[0, 1], A[1, 1], A[2, 1]]
                 ])
```

In Pytorch we could simply use `torch.stack` or simply use a `torch.tensor()` like below:

```py
tfm = torch.tensor([[A_tensor[0,0], A_tensor[1,0],0],
                    [A_tensor[0,1], A_tensor[1,1],0]
                   ])
```

However, in libtorch, this doesn't hold, that is I can not simply do:

```cpp
auto tfm = torch::tensor ({{A.index({0,0}), A.index({1,0}), A.index({2,0})},
                           {A.index({0,1}), A.index({1,1}), A.index({2,1})}
                         });
```

or even using a `std::vector` doesn't work. the same thing goes to torch::stack. I'm currently using three `torch::stack` to get this done:

```cpp
auto x = torch::stack({ A.index({0,0}), A.index({1,0}), A.index({2,0}) });
auto y = torch::stack({ A.index({0,1}), A.index({1,1}), A.index({2,1}) });
tfm = torch::stack({ x,y });
```

So is there any better way for doing this? Can we do this using a one-liner?

Comment: I feel like I do not really understand the problem here. `torch::stack({A[0][0], A[1][0], A[2][0], A[0][1], A[1][1], A[2][1]}).view(2,3);` seems to be what you are looking for. There is just the addition of `view` that differs from the python code. If that is not what you need, can you describe more precisely what it is that you are looking for ? :)

Comment: @trialNerror, oh my bad! I completely forgot about this! I dont know this scaped me but any how thats a neat reminder thank you! so kindly post this as the answer so we can call it a day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so C++ libtorch does not indeed allow tensor construction from a list of list of tensors like Pytorch (as far as I know), but you can still achieve this result with `torch::stack` (implemented [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/c4e841654dbcfdbe41298cb0991a24a4502d1257/aten/src/ATen/native/TensorShape.cpp#L1126) if you're interested) and `view` :

```
auto tfm = torch::stack( {A[0][0], A[1][0], A[2][0], A[0][1], A[1][1], A[2][1]} ).view(2,3);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot as always. by the way do you know about this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63559554/) as well? would really appreciate if you could also have a look there

Comment: I'm looking into it, and in the "comparing tensor shapes" as well ; I don't have an answer at the moment (apart from the the unhelpful "you could implement the print function yourself")